# Sitecore extend version diff popup

Tags: sitecore

Sitecore version diff popup is used to compare fields among versions of an item. But as a default it only shows user defined fields of that item(non standard fields). There is a requirement from my client asking to show comments provided by administrators when taking some actions through workbox in the version diff popup. I know that these information are saved in workflow history separately from item. Is there a way I can show these workbox information in version diff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the version diff control. 
The code is in `Sitecore.shell.Applications.Dialogs.Diff` but uses the diffviews in `Sitecore.Text.Diff.View`

You should probably override the `Compare(System.Web.UI.Control parent, Item item1, Item item2, string click)` method of the diffviews (to include the workbox comments) and the `private void Compare(string version1, string version2)` (be aware  - marked private, so you need to copy all functionality of the form to a new XAML form) of the Diff dialog to load you own diffview.

br
Klaus